# Angular 2, typescript and socket.io: onevent does not exist on type Socket

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

Long story short, in my angular app, I have to listen to all incoming events from socket.io, so I overwrote the onevent handler. Here is the snippet of interest:

```
let _onevent = socket.onevent;
socket.onevent = (packet) => {
    //do stuff
    _onevent.call(socket, packet);
};
```

Problem is when I go to build I get the error:

> Property 'onevent' does not exist on type 'Socket'.

I am using the definition file: @types/socket.io-client@^1.4.27

How can I get it to know about onevent?

Thank-you

Comment: take a look at the answer with best score here (not the accepted one ) stackoverflow.com/questions/10405070/socket-io-client-respond-to-all-events-with-one-handler

Comment: Thanks, and that is where I got the idea on how to override the event, but now typescript is giving me the above error.

Comment: Can you try `socket.onevent = function(packet) {` instead of the arrow function?

Comment: Thanks mk12ok, but still same outcome when removing the arrow function...